# how to display 20 images names in imageview

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application that consist of 20 images that are displayed as grid using custom imagepicker and display them using imageview what i need is 
1) how can i get back to image grid from image view 
2) how can i display each individual image name in image view as lable

please suggest some help and code
thank you

Answer (score 0):

If i am right then you want to create a wallpaper application,You create list of all images in a single image and put in a single view and put button in the background of all the image names(if you are using 20 images then u put 20 buttons on scrollview)and write action for all buttons,
In the next view you only change the images on the imageview.